# How to repair bootloader Ubuntu16.04LTS manually?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have windows 10 (installed in Hardisk 1) and Ubuntu 16.04LTS (installed in Hardisk 1) in my laptop, and I can select windows or Ubuntu by booting.
After updating Ubuntu / windows (I do not know exactly) I can not see the boot menu by booting, and windows starts automatically.
In UEFI-configuration, I see only 3 options: "Windows Bootmanager", "USB", "SAMSUNG .....", I think, the 3.option is related to the 2.harddisk for Ubuntu, but I am not able to change the order so that Ubuntu bootloader starts automatically.

After reading some hints from forum, I use EASYUEFI for changing it, but Ubuntu can not boot.

I think, something is wrong after updating of Ubuntu.
I installed Ext2fsd freeware for reading and writing Ubuntu partition directly from Windows. Now, I can access everything in Ubuntu-partition.

My question:
1. which file I have to modify for repairing Ubuntu GRUB bootloader?

Can someone please help me?
Best thanks
Binh

Comment: Do not mess with Ubuntu's configuration from Windows. Boot from a Linux liveCD (preferably the Ubuntu installation medium) instead to do the changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to log into a live usb installation, mount your old install, chroot into the mount, and run 'grub-install /dev/sdX' (most likely sda, could be different depending on which device is your hard drive)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: because I do not want to use a live usb installation, I wish to edit (change/modify) some files, e.g. in /boot/grub/...

Comment: Edit /etc/default/grub and look for a line GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU and change it to ="FALSE" and then run grub-update. When you boot try hitting shift to make grub boot menu appear

Comment: I did not find this line in my /etc/default/grub.

Comment: I did not find this line in my /etc/default/grub. I have only the following registrations: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: I used BootRepair for solving this problem.